# Subversive creates on checkout name with builder in it

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I currently face a strange situation, and I have no explanation for it. Here it goes ...

I provide an update site for our company, and to test that update site, I usually do a series of things. One of it is to checkout a special project from Subversion that triggers then a lot of Checkstyle and PMD rules. I use that project since at least 4 years, and it worked all the time like that:

1. Create a repository location in Eclipse.
2. Select there the project you want to checkout.
3. Select from the menu `Check Out` which uses then defaults to create a new (Java) project.

[image]

The resulting project looks like:

[image]

Since the new release (testing that with Eclipse 3.7 SR2 Indigo), I get now the following result:

[image]

So it looks like the builder(s) are now added to the project name (which seems ridiculous to me). Do I miss here something, is that a feature, not a bug? And is there anything I can do in the configuration of Subversive?

My current configuration is:

- Eclipse 3.7 SR2
- Windows 7 64bit
- JDK 1.7 64bit
- Subversive plugin

  - Subversive SVN Team Provider 1.0.0.I20121109-1700
  - Subversive SVN Connectors 3.0.0.I20121109-1700

I have added a [bug to eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394761), and will document, if there is an answer.

Comment: I can confirm the bug. Since some of us updated the Subversive SVN Team Provider to version 1.0.0.I20121109-1700 it screws up the project name. Rolling back to the previous version solved the problem for me.

Comment: Looking at the XML of the Eclipse .project file, I suspect that Subversive is creating the project name from all name fields and not just the project name field.

Comment: The Subversive guys have acknowledged the bug and fixed it. Expected to be delivered in December 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a bug at [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394761), and the bug was confirmed and fixed. So will wait the bug to be resolved in the public available update site for Subversive.